# NSView based NSTableView – strange bouncing rows for Drag and Drop with NSTableViewDraggingDestinationFeedbackStyleGap

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, drag-and-drop, nstableview

I have a view-based instance of `NSTableView` for which I’ve been changing the `draggingDestinationFeedbackStyle`, as most `NSTableView` Drag and Drop questions have been updated with reference to this method of drag animation introduced in macOS 10.9.

All works ok until I use `NSTableViewDraggingDestinationFeedbackStyleGap` for row reordering which results in my table rapidly bouncing a group of rows below the drop row.

A clue appears in my table view delegate `-validateDrop:` method which is fired numerous times and returns a `-proposedRow:` that alternates between the desired drop row and the (total number-1) of rows in the table.

A slow row move inspecting the `-validateDrop <NSDraggingInfo>` seems to point to an area just above where `NSTableViewDropOperation` becomes case On, i. e. just as it switches to case above. It only occurs within `DropOperationAbove`.

If I choose `NSTableViewDraggingDestinationFeedbackStyle` none, regular or source list everything including the `-proposedRow:` in `-validateDrop:` works correctly.

I have a custom `NSObject` set as `delegate` and also `dataSource` to fire `-validateDrop:`, while each `NSTextField` is bound to the `NSTableCellView` for specific values, so there is no `- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(nullable NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row` method.

On closer inspection, as dragging begins with `NSTableViewDraggingDestinationFeedbackStyleGap`the last row in my table is also removed and only reappears after the row has been dropped.  I have not included `-acceptDrop:` as the bouncing occurs before this is fired.

```
- (NSDragOperation)tableView:(NSTableView*)tv validateDrop:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)info proposedRow:(NSInteger)row proposedDropOperation:(NSTableViewDropOperation)op {

    NSLog(@"Validate Drop Fired in TableViewDataSource&Delegate, TableView = %@",tv);
    NSLog(@"Dragging Info = %@",info);
    NSLog(@"proposedDropOperation = %lu",(unsigned long)op);

    //Destination is self
    if ([info draggingSource] == tv) {

    NSLog(@"destination is self, and row is %li",(long)row);

    return NSDragOperationMove;
    }
return NSDragOperationNone;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];

    [myTableView registerForDraggedTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[self.arrayController entityName], nil]];

    [myTableView setDraggingDestinationFeedbackStyle:NSTableViewDraggingDestinationFeedbackStyleGap];
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)tv writeRowsWithIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)rowIndexes toPasteboard:(NSPasteboard*)pasteboard {

    NSLog(@"PasteBoard in TableViewDataSource&Delegate, with Indexes, %@",rowIndexes);
    NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:rowIndexes];


    [pasteboard declareTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[self.arrayController entityName]] owner:self];
    [pasteboard setData:data forType:[self.arrayController entityName]];

    return YES;
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView
{
    return [[arrayController arrangedObjects] count];
}
```

A single drag produces an output, for example:

```
destination is self, and row is 22
destination is self, and row is 5
destination is self, and row is 22
destination is self, and row is 5
destination is self, and row is 22
destination is self, and row is 5
```

Causing a rapid bouncing in the NSTableView instance as it jumps between trying to drop at 5, then 22, then back to 5, and so on.

I wonder if anyone has any ideas?

Comment: Please add some code to the Q, esp. of `-validateDrop:`.

Comment: Thank you for your edits and comment @amin.
Please see additional code as requested.

Comment: I think, that the move changes the index to a row that returns none operation. Therefore the gap is closed again. This triggers a move …

Comment: Thanks for your comment @amin, but on closer inspection the table is trying to drop at two different places, thus its rapidly opening and closing a row in two different places.  I'm still looking for an explanation as to why  `-validateDrop` is returning two alternating values for this specific draggingFeedbackStyle only.

Comment: Are the rows neighbours?

Comment: @amin no, it seems to be the desired row and always total number of rows -1. I've added a bit of output to the code above. Also the last row vanishes upon drag, only to reappear on drop. This has me foxed!